# How do I find a link's content type in Perl?

Tags: perl, content-type

Suppose you're given an URL, http://site.com . How do you find out what it's content type is without downloading it? Can Perl's [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize) or [LWP](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl) issue a HEAD request?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `head()` method of LWP in following manner

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->head('<url>');
```

Comment: Lucky for me mechanize inherits from UserAgent :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a full example using LWP. If you use call the `content_type` in list context, you get the type and charset as separate values:

```
use v5.10;

my $url = 'https://www.perl.com';

use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $ua->head( $url );
my( $type, $charset ) = $response->content_type;
say "LWP: Content type is ", $type;
say "LWP: charset is ", $charset;
```

Here's the same thing in Mojolicious, which doesn't break up the `Content-type` header for you.

```
use Mojo::UserAgent;
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
my $tx = $ua->head( $url );
my( $type, $charset ) =
    split /\s*;\s*/, $tx->result->headers->content_type, 2;
say "Mojo: Content type is ", $type;
say "Mojo: charset is ", $charset;
```

Some servers choke on HEAD requests, so when I do this and get an error of any sort, I retry it with a GET request and only request the first couple hundred of bytes of the resources.